# Sending a value (id for example) from one servlet to another (jsp+servlet+mysql)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, insert

I have two tables an **AFFILIATE** (**idaff**(AutoIncrement),name,address,..) and his  **COTISATION**(**id**,value,..)

> I made two separate jsp forms and two separate Servlets, each one
>   collects info from a jsp form and inserts it into the concerned table.

I would like to be able to Select/Show the AFFILIATE and his affected COTISATION(s),

```
I wanted to use idaff as a foreign key in COTISATION table, but i don't know how
 to retrieve it from the first servlet (GestAffiliate.java) to the next servlet 
(GestCotisation.java) to be able to insert it in COTISATION Table.
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Servlet Code :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
    /*response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD> <TITLE> TATATATATA </TITLE></HEAD>");
    out.println("</HTML>"); */

    Affilie newaff=new Affilie();
    newaff.setNom(request.getParameter("nom"));
    newaff.setPrenom(request.getParameter("prenom"));
    newaff.setNumaffiliation(request.getParameter("numaffiliation"));
    newaff.setCin(request.getParameter("cin"));

    newaff.setPpr(request.getParameter("ppr"));
    newaff.setNumaffilregimebase(request.getParameter("numaffregbase"));
    newaff.setMatriculeemployeur(request.getParameter("matriculeemployeur"));
    newaff.setNumpension(request.getParameter("numpension"));

    newaff.setDatenaissance(request.getParameter("datenaissance"));
    newaff.setTelephone(request.getParameter("telephone"));
    newaff.setAdresse(request.getParameter("Adresse"));
    newaff.setVille(request.getParameter("ville"));

    newaff.setCodepostal(request.getParameter("codepostal"));
    newaff.setEtatcivil(request.getParameter("etatcivil"));
    newaff.setRegime(request.getParameter("regime"));       

    Connection connection=null;
    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/authentification","root","");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `affilie` VALUES (0,'"+newaff.getNom()+"','"+newaff.getPrenom()+"','"+newaff.getNumaffiliation()+"','"+newaff.getCin()+"','"+newaff.getPpr()+"','"+newaff.getNumaffilregimebase()+"','"+newaff.getMatriculeemployeur()+"','"+newaff.getNumpension()+"','"+newaff.getDatenaissance()+"','"+newaff.getTelephone()+"','"+newaff.getAdresse()+"','"+newaff.getVille()+"','"+newaff.getCodepostal()+"','"+newaff.getEtatcivil()+"','"+newaff.getRegime()+"')");
    // ('"+newaff.getNom()+"','"+newaff.getPrenom()+"','"+newaff.getNumaffiliation()+"','"+newaff.getCin()+"','"+newaff.getPpr()+"','"+newaff.getNumaffilregimebase()+"','"+newaff.getMatriculeemployeur()+"','"+newaff.getNumpension()+"','"+newaff.getDatenaissance()+"','"+newaff.getTelephone()+"','"+newaff.getAdresse()+"','"+newaff.getVille()+"','"+newaff.getCodepostal()+"','"+newaff.getEtatcivil()+"','"+newaff.getRegime()+"'
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Cotisation.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.println(" AFFiliation PERFECTLY DONE ! ");
}
enter code here
```

Comment: what you have till tried ? post code you have tried.

Comment: i haven't i have no idea how to do it, i insert directly in the first table then insert in the second and the two have no relashionship, so that's what i'm trying to do by using AffiliateID as a ForeignKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set value of idaff in request in your servlet GestAffiliate.java

```
request.setAttribute("idaff",idaff);
```

and dispatch the request to jsp"Cotisation.jsp" and set the value in an hidden parameter there on the jsp using

```
<input type="hidden" name="idaff" value=${requestScope.idaff}>
```

and this jsp forwards to your second servlet where you can retrieve the value using

```
request.getParameter("idaff")
```

you will have to add this on your jsp page at the top of jsp page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    prefix="c" %>
```

as requestscope is offered in jstl..but it will work

Comment: I tried to give idaff a value and then print it using out.print(idaff) in the second servlet but couldn't .. Anyway i think i'll just Select max(id) since it's AutoIncrement and then insert it as FKey in the COTISATION table.
Thank you.